# Galactic Command bonus for Star Fortresses

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm trying to find information on the Galactic Command 20% daily CXP bonus based on activity.

Will doing Star Fortresses while Galactic Command has "Flashpoints" as the daily bonus give me 20% increased CXP?  Or do Star Fortresses fall under a different category?